# Hide excel workbook from vb.net

Tags: vb.net, excel, hide

http://s287.photobucket.com/user/pointy-haired-dilbert/media/hide-unhide-excel-spreadsheet.gif.html

Hello

How can I make this hide from a VB.Net application? I don't want this:

```
excelInstance.Visible = False
```

I'm searching a code for the same result as I would made this manual in Excel like this one on the Gif at the link...

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the following to hide your workbook ...

```
Windows("Book1").Visible = False
```

(where `Book1` is the name of your workbook). And this to unhide it ...

```
Windows("Book1").Visible = True
```

---

It's also worth noting that you can record a macro whilst you do something useful (like hiding the workbook) and then examine the code in the visual basic editor (Alt+F11) ... absolutely the best way to learn vba!

For instance, to answer your question, i recorded the following macro ...

```
Sub Macro1()
    ActiveWindow.Visible = False
    Windows("Book1").Visible = True
End Sub
```

As you can see, you could also use `ActiveWindow.Visible`, but once you've hidden it, it won't be active anymore so the second line references the workbook by name.

Comment: Is this still applicable in 2020? When I type in `Excel.Windows(myExcelDoc).Visible = False` it errors with "'Windows' is an interface type and cannot be used as an expression"

Comment: @Poyda That error means you're using `Windows(...)` in the wrong way ... it expects a number or a string like `Windows(1)` or `Windows("Sheet1")`, not `Windows(myExcelDoc)`, (whatever type that is?). If `myExcelDoc` is a `Workbook`, then you can just do `myExcelDoc.Visible = False`

Comment: Nope, that's what brought me here originally, because, while `myExcelDoc` is a workbook, that comes up with an error...I did work it out though... `obj Excel = Excel.Application`, then `objExcel.visible = True`